# Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in .../contact/mailtest/process.php on line 8

Tags: php, phpmailer, formmail

I'm trying to make PHPMailer work, but it keeps giving me this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /home/a4588543/public_html/contact/mailtest/process.php on line 8.

and line 8 is:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "mysmtp-server";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "me@mydomain.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "pass"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "me@mydomain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Online Request";
$mail->AddAddress("receiver@mydomain.com");                  // name is optional


$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Contact Form";
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: does class.smtp.php exist in the same folder as your script resides (mailtest folder)? Did you spell PHPMailer correctly? It is case-sensitive

Comment: Add `include_once("class.phpmailer.php");` before new instance and be sure you have `class.phpmailer.php` within `mailtest` dir.

Comment: Its good to know it MUST exist in the same folder, since in the instructions they never said It needed to.

Comment: It doesn't need to exist in the same folder if you use `require_once('./phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');` (assuming 'phpmailer' is the exact name of the directory in which you have `class.phpmailer.php` and it is a subdirectory of 'mailtest').

Answer (score 2):

If you have included all of PHPMailer's source files in the same directory, and you're using the latest version... I recommend using

```
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

The Autoload file is a great resource which saves a lot of effort when setting it up.

Comment: Sorry for the necro, but what if one does not have the autoload file?

Comment: You can obtain it by downloading the latest version of PHPMailer from their website again.

Comment: autoloader is gone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49121147/1246870