# Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found

Tags: php, phpmailer

- I tried :`include_once('C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php');`

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\index.php on line 151

I place the `PHPMailerAutoload.php` in the same directory as my script.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Where is your `PHPMailerAutoload.php` file located? Also do you include this code which you show here into another file?

Comment: in here `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\` same path as my **index.php**

Comment: based on it's name alone, it sounds like the PHPMailerAutoload.php file is trying to locate the actual class file for PHPMailer and is not able to do so.  I would look in that file to see where it's trying to look and verify that the actual class file exists in one of those locations

Comment: @Rizier123 : Should I do this then ? `require_once('C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\PHPMailerAutoload.php');`

Comment: @iori Try: `reuqire_once(__DIR__ . "/PHPMailerAutoload.php");`

Comment: I use this class in my projects and just include the actual class file, include_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

Comment: @Rizier123 : I got the same error.

Comment: @iori Do you include the code which you show us here also into another file?

Comment: Yes.I place them in the bottom section of my index.php.

Comment: So which file do you show us here? And how do you include it into index.php?

Comment: There are three files that need to be in the same directory: class.phpmailer.php, class.pop3.php, and class.smtp.php.  There is also a directory called 'language' that needs to be sitting at the same level as the 3 files I just mentioned.  This directory contains a couple dozen php files for various languages and really the only ones that are required would be for the language you are using.

Comment: Ohh I see. I thought I only need 1 file. That's I could get this to work. Thanks. I am working on it now.

Comment: @Drew : After move the whole PHPMaier folder to the same directory as my php file , and include it like this `include_once('\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php');` I think it works now. :D Thanks man

Comment: This isn't any great mystery - it's all covered in the readme, so you really didn't need to ask!

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and mark it as solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending email with PHP from an SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server)

Comment: There is no 'PHPMailerAutoload.php' in https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/src

What am I missing?

Comment: The latest version of the installation and setup instructions can always be found on the PHPMailer github page: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading

Answer (score 131):

all answers are outdated now. Most current version (as of Feb 2018) does not have autoload anymore, and PHPMailer should be initialized as follows:

```
<?php

  require("/home/site/libs/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
  require("/home/site/libs/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "xxxxxx";
    $mail->Password = "xxxx";
    $mail->SetFrom("xxxxxx@xxxxx.com");
    $mail->Subject = "Test";
    $mail->Body = "hello";
    $mail->AddAddress("xxxxxx@xxxxx.com");

     if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
        echo "Message has been sent";
     }
?>
```

Comment: Are there any further requirements? This Snippet is not working for me with 6.0.5 ---> Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' not found in PHPMailer.php on line 1411. PHPStorm warns for unhandled Exceptions too.

Comment: @aProgger use following instead 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/UPGRADING.md */
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

/* get_sendmail PHPMailer.php istenildigi zaman uzerine kaydedilmek sureti ile guncellenebilir. */
require_once('yourfolder/PHPMailer.php');

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

Comment: this really works , the trick is to put that actual path to the files or folders i.e starting from the home/site/path

Comment: `require("/home/site/libs/PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");` needs to be first line

Comment: Try with the additional slash in front of the name space like this  `$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();` for latest version.

Comment: rason # 99 to hate object oriented and use namespace crap

Comment: Working superb..!  Thank You.

Comment: I just added `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;` at the top of my file and it worked fine with `$mail = new PHPMailer();`.

Answer (score 17):

This answers in an extension to what avs099 has given above, for those who are still having problems:

1.Makesure that you have php_openssl.dll installed(else find it online and install it);

2.Go to your php.ini; find extension=php_openssl.dll enable it/uncomment

3.Go to [github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)  and downland the latetest version :6.0 at this time.

4.Extract the master copy  into the path that works better for you(I recommend  the same directory as the  calling file)

Now copy this code into your *foo-mailer*.php  and render it with your gmail stmp authentications.

```
    require("/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
    require("/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");
    require("/PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");


    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 

    $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
    $mail->Port = 465 ; //465 or 587

     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    //Authentication
    $mail->Username = "foo@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "*******";

    //Set Params
    $mail->SetFrom("foo@gmail.com");
    $mail->AddAddress("bar@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = "Test";
    $mail->Body = "hello";


     if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
        echo "Message has been sent";
     }
```

Disclaimer:The original owner of the code above is avs099 with just my little input.

Take note of the additional:

a) (PHPMailer\PHPMailer) namespace:needed for name conflict resolution.

b) The (require("/PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");):It was missing in avs099's code thus the problem encountered by aProgger,you need that line to tell the mailer class where the Exception class is located.

Answer (score 16):

As of 2021-07, and PHPMailer 6.5.0, without composer you need to do your includes in the following order:

```
$rdir = str_replace("\\", "/", __DIR__);                    //Root Dir
require $rdir.'/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require $rdir.'/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require $rdir.'/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

You may need to tweak based on your directory structure.

The rest of the code works as expected.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.yourserver.com';                  //Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'no-reply@example.com';                 //SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'password';                             //SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
$mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('mail@example.com');
$mail->addAddress('mail@example.com', 'Joe User');          //Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('mail@example.com', 'Joe Doe');           //Name is optional
$mail->addAddress('mail@example.com', 'Optional Name');     //Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//Attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');               //Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');          //Optional name

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                        //Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Doesn't sound like all the files needed to use that class are present.  I would start over:

1. Download the package from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer by clicking on the "Download ZIP" button on the far lower right of the page.
2. extract the zip file
3. upload the language folder, class.phpmailer.php, class.pop3.php, class.smtp.php, and PHPMailerAutoload.php all into the same directory on your server,  I like to create a directory on the server called phpmailer to place all of these into.
4. Include the class in your PHP project: `require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');`

Comment: I include it like this`include_once('\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php');`  , and it works also.

Comment: Just to explain my edit - As of 5.2.9 (the current release), PHPMailer does not try to load the SMTP class, nor the autoloader, so if you only load the PHPMailer class and try to send using `isSMTP`, it will break. This configuration makes it play nicely with things like composer and makes it easier to work with your own subclasses as it no longer imposes a hard dependency.

Answer (score 9):

This is just namespacing. Look at the examples for reference - you need to either use the namespaced class or reference it absolutely, for example:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue with the error. I added require_once statements for PHPMailer files and then tried to instantiate `$mail = new PHPMailer()` inside a function. Adding the `use` statements allowed the function to see the classes and removed the error.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you look into getting `composer`. https://getcomposer.org
Composer makes getting third-party libraries a LOT easier and using a single autoloader for all of them. It also standardizes on where all your dependencies are located, along with some automatization capabilities.

Download https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar to `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php`

Delete your `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\PHPMailer\` directory.

Use `composer.phar` to get the phpmailer package using the command line to execute

```
cd C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php
php composer.phar require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

After it is finished it will create a `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\vendor` directory along with all of the phpmailer files and generate an autoloader.

Next in your main project configuration file you need to include the autoload file.

`require_once 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\vendor\autoload.php';`

The `vendor\autoload.php` will include the information for you to use `$mail = new \PHPMailer;`

Additional information on the PHPMailer package can be found at https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

Comment: it also destroys your existing auto_loading, destroys your need to understand code, produces ENORMOUS project bloat, (I've seen 900 times too large projects) , infantalises your understanding of true server structure, is incredibly incompatible with any pre-existing architecture .. this `PHPMailer.php` php is a perfect example - you need three small php classes not all that bloat..  - avoid composer

Comment: @mrheelis while your assertions can be true under certain circumstances. Avoiding a dependency manager is not practical advice. In doing so you risk other aspects such as security vulnerabilities, not receiving patches of malfunctioning functions, or not including dependencies for the library you use. None-the-less your comment in general is very opinionated and subjective to your personal preference, rather than based on actual fact. In this circumstance composer would provide the autoloader and only include the required PHPMailer.

Comment: it's not an opinion, dependencies are not an enemy - all servers have them let alone software platforms - and you don't get rid of them by using composer you hide that you use them (a big difference) it's much better to document what you have installed - instead of packages simply saying  download here "use these 3 files and include these dependencies" there is a load of bloat.. it's not hard to provide organised stuff for sharing I don't know why people opt not to.. the truth is composer is (like a lot of bad ideas) messianic in it's control.. it's a rod for your back rather than a friend

Comment: @MrHeelis composer is a PSR-0/4 dependency manager, just like `yum`, `apt-get`  or `npm`. You exclaim that composer causes "bloat", but do not elaborate as to how or provide sources to back the claim. Bloat implies that composer causes apps to run slower or use more memory, which is **untrue**. While libraries can require unneeded dependencies. As such due diligence is required when using ANY 3rd party library, with or without composer. You are entitled to your "opinion", but composer is a widely renowned and utilized tool. If it did as you claim, devs would not use it in their projects.

Answer (score 2):

### NAMESPACES DO MATTER

My approach was without Composer, so I struggled knowing which line was unnecesary.

Finally, it was just a matter of including the first 3 lines for the namespaces as indicated in the instructions, then everything worked fine, like this:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require '../plugins/phpMLR/Exception.php';
require '../plugins/phpMLR/PHPMailer.php';
include '../plugins/phpMLR/SMTP.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

[...]
```

For complete debugging remember to use these lines at the beggining:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem except with a slight difference, the version of PHPMailer 6.0, by the good friend avs099 I know that the new version of PHPMailer since February 2018 does not support the autoload, and had a serious problem to instantiate the libraries with the namespace in MVC, I leave the code for those who need it.

```
//Controller
    protected function getLibraryWNS($libreria) {
    $rutaLibreria = ROOT . 'libs' . DS . $libreria . '.php';

    if(is_readable($rutaLibreria)){
        require_once $rutaLibreria;
        echo $rutaLibreria . '<br/>';
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception('Error de libreria');
    }
}

//loginController
    public function enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo){
    //Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
            $this->getLibraryWNS('PHPMailer');
            $this->getLibraryWNS('SMTP');
    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
            $mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
            $mail->isSMTP();
    //Enable SMTP debugging
    //      $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                       // 0 = off (for production use),  1 = client messages, 2 = client and server messages  Godaddy POR CONFIRMAR
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                                       // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                     // authentication enabled
    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                                  //Seguridad Correo Gmail
    //Set the hostname of the mail server
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";                             //Host Correo Gmail
    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
            $mail->Port = 465;      //587;
    //Verifica si el servidor acepta envios en HTML
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
            $mail->Username = 'tumail@gmail.com';
    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
            $mail->Password = 'tucontraseña';
    //Set who the message is to be sent from
            $mail->setFrom('tumail@gmail.com','Creador de Páginas Web');
            $mail->Subject = $asunto;
            $mail->Body = $cuerpo;
    //Set who the message is to be sent to
            $mail->addAddress($email, $nombre);
    //Send the message, check for errors
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } else {
        echo "Message has been sent";
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from reading what you have written, you will need to add the file class.phpmailer.php to your directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

`PHPMailerAutoload` needs to be in the same folder as `class.phpmailer.php`

This is the `PHPMailerAutoload` code that I assume this:

```
 $filename = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($classname).'.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just download composer and install phpMailler autoloader.php

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/composer.json

once composer is loaded use below code:

    require_once("phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    require_once("phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
            $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
            $mail->Username   = 'youremail id';
            $mail->Password   = 'youremail password';
            $mail_from        = "youremail id";
            $subject          = "Your Subject";
            $body             = "email body";
            $mail_to          = "receiver_email";
            $mail->IsSMTP(); 
            try {
                  $mail->Host= "smtp.your.com";
                  $mail->Port = "Your SMTP Port No";// ssl port :465, 
                  $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
                  $mail->AddAddress($mail_to, "receiver_name");
                  $mail->SetFrom($mail_from,'AmpleChat Team'); 
                  $mail->Subject = $subject;
                  $mail->MsgHTML($body);
                  $mail->Send();
                 $emailreturn = 200;
                } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
                  $emailreturn = $e->errorMessage();             
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                 $emailreturn = $e->getMessage();
                }
    echo $emailreturn;
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved error copying the files class.phpmailer.php , class.smtp.php to the folder where the file is PHPMailerAutoload.php, of course there should be the file that we will use to send the email.

Answer (score -1):

I had a number of errors similar to this. Make sure your setFrom email address is valid in `$mail->setFrom()`