# Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, require

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\wamp\www\sendemail.php on line 13
```

This is line 13:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

I have already researched and they say you need to have these:

```
require_once('class.pop3.php');
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

But I already have those and they reside in the same folder as sendemail.php but still the same error.

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
*/
//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require_once('class.pop3.php');
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "email@email.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "password";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('email@email.com', 'name');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('email@sample.com', 'name');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Here is my file layout:

[image: File layout]

Comment: Do you have a namespace in your _sendemail.php_?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Did you add required lib files in sendemail.php ?

Comment: I edited my question to add the sendemail.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906487/fatal-error-class-phpmailer-not-found

Comment: I've already read that and it was solved by putting the file into the same folder. Different case for me

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue, and managed to solve it by entering the following two lines at the very top of the PHP script used for sending the mail - not just in the files I `require`d.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
?>
```

Let me know if it works for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Add all those extra `require` lines are not going to help; Just load the autoloader, like the original example code says. Try loading it from an absolute path:

```
require '/full/path/to/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

If that works, you need to check that your [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) setting in php.ini includes the directory you're loading from - for example that it contains `.` as one of the paths.

I'm pretty convinced this is an environment/config problem, not code, so try a completely minimal script, just this:

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

If you're doing new development, you should really be using [composer](https://getcomposer.org) anyway - it completely solves include problems and you'll never have to worry about where your libraries are again.

Comment: I am using WAMP, and it already knows that I'm inside the 'www' folder so it should still see "PHPMailerAutoload.php" but I still tried 'www/PHPMailerAutoLoad.php' but it says this Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'www/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

Comment: My windows include path is this ; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"

Comment: Don't assume, check. Try the absolute path.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in C:\wamp\www\sendemail.php on line 13

Comment: Note that `.` and the location of the file you are calling from are not necessarily the same - `__DIR__.'/file.php'` and `./file.php` may be different paths.

Comment: That error is not the require failing - do you have duplicate files in your paths?

Comment: no duplicate files. what do you mean by this __DIR__.'/file.php'?

Comment: `__DIR__` Is a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) that points to the directory that the current file is in. It might help if you showed a screen shot of your file layout in your question. It's really not clear where you're putting stuff at present.

Comment: That arrangement looks fine. The error you're getting is not that it can't find or load the file - your `require` statements are working fine -  it's that it can't instantiate the class for some reason.

Comment: I guess I'm stuck.