# How to integrate PHPMailer with Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

Hi I am trying to use [PHPMailer Library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)  from GitHUB in my Codeigniter application.

I downloaded the code and unzipped in my `application\library` folder.
So there I have a folder called **vendor** inside which resides the source code for  PHPMailer.

Now I created a File named `Bizmailer_Controller.php`.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
* 
*/
class Bizmailer_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        require "vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\PHPMailerAutoload";
        $this->Bizmailer = new PHPMailer();
        //Set the required config parameters
        $this->Bizmailer->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $this->Bizmailer->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $this->Bizmailer->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $this->Bizmailer->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
        $this->Bizmailer->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
        $this->Bizmailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $this->Bizmailer->Port = 465;    
        //return $api;
    }
}
```

Now in my controllers I am trying to load it like this :

```
$this->load->library('Bizmailer');
$mail = new Bizmailer();
```

And I Get this error :

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load the requested class: Bizmailer

So Please guide me how I can load or integrate this library in Codeigniter.

Comment: just out of curiosity - is there a reason why you want to use phpmailer instead of the standard mail library from codeigniter ?

Comment: @sintakonte Yes, actually This allows me to set alias for all my different email accounts which i did not find in Codeigniter's library `$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I have tried Codeigniter native library and it works fine, but because i have requirement where i want to set an alias for my emails. Like my actual email would be rajan@example.com  but i want them to show mail received from info@example.com

Answer (score 20, accepted):

here is a guide

### 1. installing PHP Mailer

Download the latest PHPMailer Build from Github.
You can find the project [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Click now on "clone or download" and download it as zip - as in the image below is shown.
[image: PHP Mailer Download as ZIP]

The folder in the zip is called PHPMailer-master.
Unzip this in your application/third_party/ folder and rename the folder to phpmailer. You should see something like this
[image]

### 2. PHP Mailer Library

Imho its best to create a library which handles your PHPMailer Object (Phpmailer_library.php)
This library could look like

```
class Phpmailer_library
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        log_message('Debug', 'PHPMailer class is loaded.');
    }

    public function load()
    {
        require_once(APPPATH."third_party/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
        $objMail = new PHPMailer;
        return $objMail;
    }
}
```

### 3. Using this library in one of your controllers, models etc.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library("phpmailer_library");
        $objMail = $this->phpmailer_library->load();
    }
}
```

i think this should pretty much do the job.
If you've any troubles, don't hesitate to ask ;)

---

### Update 25.06.2018

Since the PHPMailer guys removed the autoloader you've two options now:

**1.) via Composer**

for those who didn't know - Codeigniter supports Composer - you simply have to activate the autoload - you can find this in your config.php

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = true;
```

For more informations take a look [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=composer)

After that - run composer like

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

You now should have within your `application/vendor` folder the `phpmailer` files.

The library should look like

```
class Phpmailer_library
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        log_message('Debug', 'PHPMailer class is loaded.');
    }

    public function load()
    {
        $objMail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
        return $objMail;
    }
}
```

**2.) download**

follow step 1

The library should look like

```
class Phpmailer_library
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        log_message('Debug', 'PHPMailer class is loaded.');
    }

    public function load()
    {
        require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
        require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php');

        $objMail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
        return $objMail;
    }
}
```

and everything else should remain the same

Comment: This is perfect, just one question, can I declare my global settings in PHPMailer_Library.php constructor  ? Will those be available to me though out other controllers?

Comment: of course you can - its mandatory to know although - that you need a new function in your library if you wish other settings ;)

Comment: Hi, sorry to reply so late but I get the error unable to load class PHPMailer_Library. Why is that?

Comment: Whats your environment ? Linux or Windows ?

Comment: autoloader is gone from PHPMailer now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49121147/1246870

Comment: @JianYA Phpmailer_library.php must be located within libraries folder.

Comment: I've followed all the steps, but when I run it gives me error `Unable to load the requested class: Phpmailer_lib`

Answer (score 7):

**

### UPDATE AUGUST 2019

**

At first, download the latest [PHPMailer library files](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/src) and place all the files in the application/third_party/ folder of your CodeIgniter application.

Now, create a library (application/libraries/Phpmailer_lib.php) to handle the PHPMailer object.

- Include the PHPMailer library files.
- Initialize the PHPMailer class.
- Return the PHPMailer object.

  ```
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
  class PHPMailer_Lib
  {
  public function __construct(){
      log_message('Debug', 'PHPMailer class is loaded.');
  }

  public function load(){
      // Include PHPMailer library files
      require_once APPPATH.'third_party/phpmailer/Exception.php';
      require_once APPPATH.'third_party/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
      require_once APPPATH.'third_party/phpmailer/SMTP.php';

      $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
      return $mail;
  }
  }
  ```

Now send email via SMTP server using PHPMailer from your controller using this code.

```
class Email extends CI_Controller{

    function  __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function send(){
        // Load PHPMailer library
        $this->load->library('phpmailer_lib');

        // PHPMailer object
        $mail = $this->phpmailer_lib->load();

        // SMTP configuration
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host     = 'smtp.example.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';
        $mail->Password = '********';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Port     = 465;

        $mail->setFrom('info@example.com', 'CodexWorld');
        $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'CodexWorld');

        // Add a recipient
        $mail->addAddress('john.doe@gmail.com');

        // Add cc or bcc 
        $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
        $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

        // Email subject
        $mail->Subject = 'Send Email via SMTP using PHPMailer in CodeIgniter';

        // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        // Email body content
        $mailContent = "<h1>Send HTML Email using SMTP in CodeIgniter</h1>
            <p>This is a test email sending using SMTP mail server with PHPMailer.</p>";
        $mail->Body = $mailContent;

        // Send email
        if(!$mail->send()){
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }else{
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hey, how do I call the controller to send the email? I've tried but no idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is php mailer library for Codeigniter 2/3, you can check [this](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-28.html) and [this](https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer).

Answer (score 0):

What about putting it on helper?

First you need to have composer installed in your local.
If not then google how to install it.

Then get phpmailer using composer by opening cmd then make a folder for PHPMailer files.
Then type command : composer require phpmailer/phpmailer

Here my code :

1. Copy all files in folder "vendor" in your phpmailer folder to your web app in folder "/system/application/vendor/"
2. Open one of your helper file (or create new helper file) in "/system/application/helper/"
3. Use this code

   ```
   function sendemail($to,$to_name,$subject,$message){ 
       require_once APPPATH.'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
       require_once APPPATH.'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
       require_once APPPATH.'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

       //Make instance of PHPMailer object
       $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();  

       // SMTP configuration
       $mail->isSMTP();
       $mail->Host     = 'mail.yoursite.com';
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
       $mail->Username = 'accountname@yoursite.com';
       $mail->Password = 'yourpassword';
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  
       $mail->Port     = 465;

       $mail->setFrom('accountname@yoursite.com', 'your name');
       //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'CodexWorld');

       // Add a recipient
       $mail->addAddress($to); //,$to_name


       // Add cc or bcc 
       $mail->addCC('youraccount@yoursite.com', 'your name');

       // Set email format to HTML
       $mail->isHTML(true);

       // Email subject
       $mail->Subject = $subject; 

       // Email body content
       $mailContent = $message."<br/><br/>
           <p>Auto notification *** <br/>DO NOT REPLY TO THIS ADDRESS as it is not attended.</p>";
       $mail->Body = $mailContent;

       // Send email
       if(!$mail->send()){
           echo 'Message could not be sent.';
           echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; die;
       }else{
          //do none or celebrate may be???
       }
   }
   ```
4. To call the method, you need to load the helper then call the method like below:

   ```
   $this->load->helper('yourhelper');
   sendemail("blabla@yahoo.com","to name","Subject","Email content ( can use html)");
   ```