# codeigniter: Send email via localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have configured php.ini, sendmail.ini and also used the right port and configuration for gmail, I also enable lesssecure apps on gmail but I could see mail when i check inbox and it shows no error

Here's the controller

```
                   $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
                    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
// SMTP Port - the port that you is required
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = $sender_email;
$config['smtp_pass'] = $sender_password;
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->from($sender_email);
$this->email->to($to_email);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
                    if(!$this->email->send()) {
                        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                    }
                    else{
                        echo 'Your email has been sent!<br/>';
                    }

                echo $message2; //send this in email
```

php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
auth_username= xxxx.gmail.com
auth_password= xxxx
```

Comment: use php mailer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843305/how-to-integrate-phpmailer-with-codeigniter-3

Comment: Thanks, but finding it difficult to get my head around configuration

Comment: Can you help with it?

Comment: @johnconde why did you mark my question as duplicate when the answer you provided doesn't apply with codeigniter

Comment: $config['protocol'] = 'smtps';

Comment: @N.francis It applies to all sending of mail with PHP. *Some* of it is specific to the `mail()` function but *most* of it applies to the sending of email with PHP regardless of mailer.

Comment: @JohnConde Well, I've tried virtually everything, but i still don't receive mails and it doesn't display error. Could you find time to take a look. Thanks

Comment: @ChaitanyaDesai,Thanks but didn't work

Comment: @JohnConde, I know how to code it on live server, but I want to do it on xammp

Answer (score 0):

You can use below tool to test emails on localhost. Setup is rather easy and clearly explained in the description.
[Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/)