# Codeigniter: Ensure Emails are send when Email Provider has technical issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Im developing an application in Codeigniter which is highly dependent on properly sended emails. Our E-Mail Server Provider recently had technical issues and thus our app wasnt able to send mails. Im using the Codeigniters own E-Mail sending method:

```
$sendState = $instance->email->send ();
```

This method didnt return false nor produced any errors while the Provider had technical issues, but emails werent send. Is there any way to ensure Emails are properly send in Codeigniter or PHP in general?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: propably not - because if the mail server is accessible and gives you a success back - it doesnt necessarly mean it sends your emails. a better library would be `PHPMailer` at least you get more information - depending on the debug level, take a look @ https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, if you find that informative, i once wrote a guide how to use that library under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843305/how-to-integrate-phpmailer-with-codeigniter-3

Comment: You can use mailgun for email. Its widely used and give proper response.

Comment: ok thx for the suggestions