# PHPMailer class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

I have PHPMailer working in my code in my local enviroment but when I move it to the server I get the following error

```
Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found
```

Heres the bit of code that im using:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

class Email extends EV_DB {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->email_common  = [
      'baseurl' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
    ];
    $this->stache = new Mustache_Engine(array(
        'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader( __DIR__ .'/../../mustache'),
    'partials_loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader( __DIR__  .'/../../mustache/partial')
));
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
...
```

I installed PHPMailer with composer, and have my codeigniter setup to autoload in a config file, which is why theres not require for the autoload.php. I'm sure this is working correctly since mustache loads just fine, and if I try to manually include the autload file it gives me the error:

```
Cannot declare class ComposerAutoloaderInitb315d7432979fc7d6789bb454c858180, because the name is already in use.
```

The difference between my local and live enviroments is that I have the application folder separate from where the index.php lives. So in the index.php I have set:

```
$application_folder = 'C:\inetpub\my_application\application';
```

while the index file lives in

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication\index.php
```

Is this location change changing the what the namespace should be set as? I don't really know enough to troubleshoot past this point.

Comment: show how phpmailer is defined in composer please?

Comment: @Alex "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0"

Comment: just a hunch, maybe the namespace is wrong. have you tried: use PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\Exception;

Comment: @billrichards Tried that, same issue.

Comment: i once wrote a guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843305/how-to-integrate-phpmailer-with-codeigniter-3#answer-44844337 - maybe it helps - but tbh i don't see any error - are you sure those files are on your server ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end reinstalling PHPMailer through composer did the trick. I guess something went wrong during installation. Whoops.