# php - using namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to use minimal features of `phpmailer`. this is my folder structure:

```
webroot/
  - php/
     - mail.php
     - phpmailer/
         - PHPMailer.php
```

in my `mail.php`, i want to use the namespace:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
...
```

But I got error:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in
>   /home/example/public_html/php/mail.php on line 2

How can I resolve this?

Comment: have you tried `use phpmailer\PHPMailer;`?

Comment: namespace are declared as `namespace nameOfSpace`, use will try to import a class.

Comment: And what? Do you have autoloader or how do you include phpmailer files?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create include.php file.

   ```
     $LibraryPath = "/webroot/php";
     set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $LibraryPath);
   ?>
   ```

*Where $LibaryPath is the path of your php folder which contains the phpmailer folder

2. In your PhpMailer.php include

   ```
       namespace phpmailer;

       class PHPMailer(){
       .....
       }
       ?>
   ```
3. In mail.php include the require so you can instantiate phpmailer\PHPMailer

   ```
   require ('include.php');

   use phpmailer\PHPMailer;
   ```

You can add more class inside the php folder and you can define their namespaces following #2.

You can call them in new pages by including 'include.php' and instantiating the class.

Answer (score 0):

Start looking into composer. Composer will help you using a single autoloader.

[Download: Composer](https://getcomposer.org)

Put composer inside php folder.

Have a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906487/fatal-error-class-phpmailer-not-found)

OR put the class inside the php project.

You need all these:

```
require_once('class.pop3.php');
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

[PHPMailer Github link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 0):

PhpMailer doesn't seem to be in a namespace.

include phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php and use \PHPMailer :

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' ;
use \PHPMailer ;
```